# Does Android SDK work in Solaris?

Tags: android, solaris

I want to compile my Android app in a Solaris server. Though, from  [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) all I can see are Windows/MacOS/Linux versions. Does anyone know if I can install and use the Linux binaries in a Solaris machine? If not, are there alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of native code (emulator, dex conversion, tools), not only Java, so no. Install Linux in a VM (VirtualBox, VMWare, etc.) and use it for development.